# How do I justify this block of text and bring it in front of the icon?

Tags: sass, css-selectors, font-awesome

Using the following CSS:

```
.notice--info::before {
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    top: .5em;
    left: 0;
    color: #ff980052;
    content: "\f071 ";
    font-size: 4em;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    line-height: .1em;
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

I've managed to achieve this look:

[image: Screen Shot of Site]

Using this Kramdown markup in Jekyll on the Minimal Mistakes theme:

```
{: .notice--info}
Important: Our systems are evolving and becoming more and more interconnected and dependent upon one another.  Therefore, we're providing a single checklist to handle all aspects of the morning prep so we can all work as a team on all aspects of the production.
```

The goal is to add font awesome icons as watermarks to the [Minimal Mistakes Utility Classes](https://mmistakes.github.io/minimal-mistakes/docs/utility-classes/#notices) defaults.

**QUESTION 1:** How do I get the first line to overlap without indentation?
**QUESTION 2:** How do I bring the text to the front so it's the top layer and isn't washed out by the alpha channel of the Font Awesome icon?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've gone about re-creating your intended effect using **Unicode** rather than **Font Awesome** because you can achieve so much these days with a combination of **Unicode** and **CSS filters** that a third-party dependency like **Font Awesome** (which was popular in the early 2010s) may not be necessary any more.

Principally,

- I've given the paragraph `text-align: justify`
- I've made the paragraph see-through, by giving it an `rgba()` `background-color`
- Finally, I've positioned the warning symbol beneath the paragraph, using a `z-index` of `-6`

**Working Example:**

```css
.notice--info {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 12px 30px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: rgba(187, 197, 224, 0.3);
}

.notice--info::before {
  content: '\26A0 \FE0F';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 42px;
  left: 6px;
  z-index: -6;
  font-size: 80px;
  filter: hue-rotate(-10deg) saturate(8);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<p class="notice--info"><strong>Important:</strong> Our systems are evolving and becoming more and more interconnected and dependent upon one another.  Therefore, we're providing a single checklist to handle all aspects of the morning prep so we can all work as a team on all aspects of the production.</p>
```